# PostgreSQL stored procedure: How to insert from a variable

Tags: stored-procedures, postgresql-9.3

I am trying to write a stored procedure which parses the input JSON into a record and populates the various tables with JSON content. The problem is that I cannot figure out how to use a variable in INSERT. My table, type and the stored procedure are defined as:

```
REATE TYPE  resource_raw AS (
  "field1" text ,
  "field2" text ,
  "field3" text,
  "field4" text
};
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS actual_table (
   field1 text,
   field2 text
};

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION discovery_graph.populate_resource(json_in json)
  RETURNS resource_raw AS
 $BODY$DECLARE
   raw_record resource_raw;
 BEGIN   
   SELECT  json_populate_record( NULL::resource_raw, json_in) INTO raw_record;
 INSERT INTO actual_table (field1, field2) SELECT (field1, field2) FROM raw_record;
  RETURN raw_record;
END;
 $BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

The problem is that when I execute the procedure I get an error:

```
ERROR:  relation "raw_record" does not exist
LINE 1: ...field1, field2) FROM raw_record
```

I am wondering what I am doing wrong in using the variable for INSERT?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `FROM raw_record` in your `INSERT` as `raw_record` is not a table. This will run without errors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION populate_resource(json_in json)
  RETURNS resource_raw AS
 $BODY$DECLARE
   raw_record resource_raw;
 BEGIN   
   SELECT  json_populate_record(NULL::resource_raw, json_in) INTO raw_record;
 INSERT INTO actual_table (field1, field2) (SELECT raw_record.field1, raw_record.field2);
  RETURN raw_record;
END;
 $BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;
```

More detailed info about the variables in the documentation, for example: [40.10. PL/pgSQL Under the Hood - variable substitution](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/plpgsql-implementation.html#PLPGSQL-VAR-SUBST)